# Swagger editor always gives error on json

Tags: json, swagger

For me not a single json string worked with the swagger editor.

Here is an example which i took from the page:

```
{
"swaggerVersion": "2.0",
"basePath": "http://localhost:8000/greetings",
"apis": [
{
  "path": "/hello/{subject}",
  "operations": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "summary": "Greet our subject with hello!",
      "type": "string",
      "nickname": "helloSubject",
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "subject",
          "description": "The subject to be greeted.",
          "required": true,
          "type": "string",
          "paramType": "path"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
],
"models": {}
}
```

So current error for this, is:

```
✖ YAML Syntax Error
Missed comma between flow collection entries at line 2, column 14: "swagger: "2.0", ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where did you take the base code for but that syntax seems to be totally wrong (at least for swagger 2), I recommend you to take a look to [the official specification](http://swagger.io/specification/).

About the code you pasted, I refactorized it, try with this one:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "host": "localhost:8000",
    "basePath": "/greetings",
    "info": {
        "title": "Some title",
        "version": "0.0.1"
    },
    "paths": {
        "/hello/{subject}": {
            "get": {
                "summary": "Greet our subject with hello!",
                "parameters": [{
                    "name": "subject",
                    "description": "The subject to be greeted.",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string",
                    "in": "path"
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "default": {
                        "description": "Some description",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i had it form https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/wiki/Hello-World-Sample

Answer (score 0):

Even though the OP's syntax was wrong, this is for other people who are searching for an answer and **their syntax is correct**.

**If you are getting the JSON data from the browser** and you have a browser extension that formats and displays nicely the JSON data, it might cause trouble (because of the formatting) when pasting in Swagger Editor.

If that's the case, try disabling the extension or go incognito.

Comment: The provided sample json was copied from https://github.com/reverb/swagger-spec/wiki/Hello-World-Sample.